# import configurable products from XML file

Tags: configurable-product, import, products

I'm trying to import products to my from XML link :

http://fulyan.com.tr/xml/?R=35116&K=6d2c&Imgs=1&AltUrun=1&TamLink

but it imports configurable product as a simple product. in XML file configurable products comes as -subproducts- 
but I couldn't link associated products in Magento to sub-products in XML files.

Comment: what process are you using to import the xml, the native importer or a custom tool?